# Pagination RTL next and previous arrowsheads are facing in the wrong direction material ui react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, pagination

related to this issue

https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/20193

Pagination Arrow Working on reverse on RTL direction

Answer (score 1):

just change the theme by following code:

```js
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

export const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiPagination: {
      defaultProps: {
        dir: "ltr",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

then use this code to change arrows:

```js
<Pagination
                count={pageCount}
                page={page}
                onChange={(e, newPage: number) => setPage(newPage)}
                renderItem={item => (
                  <PaginationItem
                    components={{ previous: ArrowForward, next: ArrowBack }}
                    {...item}
                  />
                )}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

From `Mui` Documentation:

> Right-to-left languages such as Arabic, Persian, or Hebrew are supported. To change the direction of MUI components you must follow the following steps.

Documentation and Demo:
https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/right-to-left/#demo

`Pagination` in `RTL` Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/direction-material-demo-forked-zdgsi8?file=/demo.js

Comment: const cacheRtl = createCache({
    key: lang === "ar" ? "muirtl" : "muiltr",
    stylisPlugins: lang === "ar" ? [prefixer, rtlPlugin] : []
  }); i had all configuration but still showing me rotated arrows in second time toggeling from english to arabic

Comment: >1 2 3 < instead of  <1 2 3>

Comment: You don't have to change `CacheProvider` `value` in toggeling !     
Just toggle between 2 Mui Themes with directions `ltr` and `rtl`, and change the direction of `document.body`.    
I've Update the Demo, chaeck it: https://codesandbox.io/s/direction-material-demo-forked-zdgsi8?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 0):

you can Change Arrow Icons like this:
The Previous Button change it to Forward Button and the Next Button Change it to Back Button :) Enjoy!! XD

reference For changing icons: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-pagination/#custom-icons

```
 <Pagination
                count={pageCount}
                page={page}
                onChange={(e, newPage: number) => setPage(newPage)}
                renderItem={item => (
                  <PaginationItem
                    components={{ previous: ArrowForward, next: ArrowBack }}
                    {...item}
                  />
                )}
              />
```